# Jersey EventOutput delays data delivery

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, server-sent-events

I use SSE to ping my clients. A ping request is send over SSE, the client answers the request via POST. Somehow my ping-requests often arrive delayed on the clients. The delay seems to be directly correlated to the ping timeout that is used.

Client Class:

```
public synchronized boolean ping(int timeout){

        final OutboundEvent event = EventFactory.newPingEvent();
        if (eventSink.isClosed()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                responseReceived.set(false);
                requestTimestamp.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                eventSink.write(event);
                waitForResponseOrTimeout(timeout);
                boolean clientAnswered = responseReceived.get();
                return result;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
}

public void onPingResponse() {
    responseReceived.set(true);
    responseTimestamp.set(System.currentTimeMillis());

    synchronized (this) {
        notifyAll();
    }
}
private void waitForResponseOrTimeout(int timeout) {
    boolean timeoutExpired;
    do {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                wait(timeout);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Wait was interrupted", ex);
        }
        timeoutExpired = getElapsedTime() > timeout;
    } while (!(timeoutExpired || responseReceived.get()));
}
```

REST-API Class:

```
@POST
@Path("{ClientId}")
public void pingResponse(@PathParam("ClientId") String id){
   Client client=getClientById(id);
   client.onPingResponse();
}
```

Where does this delay come from and how to avoid it?